# How do extend a rectangle in the background of my ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have an stacked bar chart with differing widths that I have created in R.

[image]

I have added a rectangle in the background to highlight the first element of the barchart using the following code

```
cum_height=c(102398248,172861064,102398248,172861064,102398248,172861064,102398248,172861064,102398248,172861064,102398248,172861064,102398248,172861064,102398248,172861064)
width=c(0.69,1,1,0.95,1,0.88,1,0.36,1,0.84,0.69,1,0.36,1,0.21,1)
   Quartile=c(3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,4,4,4,4)
Intensity=c('Land','Land','N','N','P','P','K','K','GHG','GHG','Green Water','Green Water','Surface Water','Surface Water','Ground Water','Ground Water')
height=c(102398248,70462816,102398248,70462816,102398248,70462816,102398248,70462816,102398248,70462816,102398248,70462816,102398248,70462816,102398248,70462816)
All_variables<-data.frame(width,Intensity,cum_height,Quartile,height)

All_variables$Intensity <- factor(All_variables$Intensity, levels = rev(unique(All_variables$Intensity)), ordered=TRUE)

ggsave(filename = "Wheatexample.jpg",ggplot(All_variables, aes(Intensity, y=cum_height- 0.5 * height, fill =factor(Quartile))) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0, ymax=cum_height[[1]] , xmin ="Land", xmax = "Ground Water"), fill =alpha("gray",0.2))+
  geom_tile(aes(width = (width)*0.5, height = height),color="black", show.legend = TRUE)+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Quartile", values=c("#ffffb2", "#fecc5c", "#fd8d3c", "#e31a1c"))+
  xlab ("Footprint (per ton)")+
  ylab("Total Production (Tons)")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
    axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold")),
  width = 12, height =8, dpi = 300, units = "in", device='jpg')
```

The problem is that I can't get the grey background to extend beyond the land and Ground Water titles and if I use a different numerical or Inf value as my xmin and xmax I get a:

```
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

I want the grey rectangle to extend to the area scored in black shown in this image:

[image: Where I want to extend the rectangle]

Comment: Please add the results of `dput(Matrix)`, `dput(rects1)` and `dput(Barchart_Variables) ` into the question to make this reproducible. Thanks.  Also, its usually not recommended to give your variables the same names as common functions (such as Matrix).

Comment: Do you 'simply' want to extend the grey area until the y-axis or beyond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there!! Your problem was that you are using `coord_flip`, which can often be confusing when specifying x and y axes.

The `Inf` should be in your `y` limits! see below

```
ggplot(All_variables, aes(Intensity, y=cum_height- 0.5 * height, fill =factor(Quartile))) +
         geom_rect(aes(ymin = -Inf, ### here we go!! 
         ymax=cum_height[[1]] , xmin ="Land", xmax = "Ground Water"), fill = alpha("gray",0.2))+
         geom_tile(aes(width = (width)*0.5, height = height),color="black", show.legend = TRUE) +
          coord_flip()
```

[image]

---

**edit**
as per your request here how to make extend the grey rectangle to both x and y axis. The error is pointing to the problem: You have both continuous and discrete scales for your x axis, you need to change either the continuous to discrete or discrete to continuous. Here, because you want to use `Inf`, it is more straight forward to change your discrete x into a continuous variable

```
ggplot(All_variables) + 
# I removed aesthetic specifications from your main call. 
# Some people advise to leave this call completely empty. 
# It makes it easier and less "buggy" to make several plots. 
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = -Inf, ### as before 
                ymax= cum_height[[1]] , 
                xmin =Inf, 
                xmax = -Inf), fill = alpha("gray",0.2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = as.numeric(Intensity), 
# here I am transforming discrete to continuous
                y=cum_height- 0.5 * height, fill =factor(Quartile),
                width = (width)*0.5, height = height),color="black", show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:8, labels = levels(All_variables$Intensity))+
# now you of course have to specify the breaks and the labels of your x-axis
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Tjebo. Thanks for your help but I want to extend both the  x and y axis.

Comment: Yes I have added an image to my question showing where I want to extend it to